# The "abc" parameter is missing a value

Tags: sql, visual-studio, parameters

I'm having problems with a SQL Reporting Services 2005 report prompting for a parameter value, which is set as a list of values from a query.

When navigating to the report directly, or using a "jump to hyperlink" and specifying the reports url, it works fine.  However when it's accessed via a link from another report using "jump to report", it doesn't prompt for a parameter and gives an error stating "The 'abc' parameter is missing a value".

Everything works fine when debugging in VS 2005, however the error appears after it's been deployed.

Any ideas???????

Answer (score 0):

After reading this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/86df7ebf-d63f-44a3-ad80-ed0c0ed60bf4

I was able to bypass the "Jump to report" using the "Jump to URL" using the following:

=Globals!ReportServerUrl & "?%2f" & MID(Globals!ReportFolder, 2, LEN(Globals!ReportFolder)) & "%2f" & Fields!ReportModule.Value